# Activerecord: query with true does not show any result for boolean fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `users` table with a boolean field active. I have users in the database with `active: true`. The problem, following query does not give any result

```
@users = User.where(active: true)  #this results to empty array
```

But if I give 1 instead of true then I get the results.

```
@users = User.where(active: 1)  #this gives correct result
```

I don't understand why true is not working.

Comment: in the schema file is user active set as a boolean?

Comment: what does this return for `active` column on `users` table on your sql client `SELECT "users"."id", "users"."active" FROM "users";` ? `true/false` or `0/1` ?

Comment: it returns 0/1, but my schema says field active is boolean and also when I run query like `User.first.active` this result true not 0/1

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite

Comment: Can you try `@users = User.where("active = ?", true)` let me know if that works

Comment: This gives empty array.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

You can check [data type of SQLite here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

So you save user with active true, but in database `active` field has value `1`, that's why `User.where(active: 1)` works.